# TextGrid wouldn't render in the FormPage deployed in the Cloud

Tags: formpage

Consider the following testing FormPage being deployed on the cloud.

```
CloudDeploy@FormPage[{
    "Testing"->{1,2,3}
},
    TextGrid[{{"", "", 2, 3}, {"\[Times]", "", "", 7}, {"+", 1, 6, 1}, {"", 1, 6, 1}}, Alignment -> {Right, Baseline}, Dividers -> {{{False}}, {3 -> True, -2 -> True}}, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]&
]
```

If you run the `FormPage` without `CloudDeploy` locally it renders the TextGrid correctly but if you deploy it in the cloud and run it there it wouldn't render.

Is it a bug or am i missing something?

Possible workarounds please in case of bug.